# Counting functions, with certain properties.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am asking whether my solution to the following problem is correct.

Q: How many distinct functions f from {1,2,3,4,5} to {1,2,3} are there such that there exists at least one $i \in$ {1,2,3,4,5} for which $f(i)=i$

My logic:

The total number of distinct functions is $3^5 = 243$ such functions. Now count the number of functions which there is no $i \in$ {1,2,3,4,5} for which $f(i)=i$, is $2$ x $2$ x $2$ x $3$ x $3$ = $72$ such functions. So the number of functions for which there is at least one $i \in$ {1,2,3,4,5} for which $f(i)=i$ is $ 243 - 72 = 171 $ such functions.

Please can someone let me know if I am correct? I have an exam tomorrow so would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: It seems a good solution.